# A database query error has occurred. This may indicate a bug in the software

Tags: pdf

I am trying to upload **PDF** about **5 Mb** to **Mediawiki** and I am facing this error.

> A database query error has occurred. This may indicate a bug in the
> software.

**php.ini** has

> upload_max_filesize = 32M
>
> post_max_size = 32M

File extensions are configured like

```
$wgFileExtensions = array_merge( $wgFileExtensions,
    array( 'doc', 'xls', 'mpp', 'pdf', 'ppt', 'xlsx', 'jpg', 
        'tiff', 'odt', 'odg', 'ods', 'odp'
    )
);
```

**Mediawiki** is configured to upload files up to **32 Mb**.

Also I am faciong this error

> Error creating thumbnail: /bin/bash: convert: command not found GPL
> Ghostscript 9.07: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1

Any clue?

P.S. I discovered that is possible to upload small PDFs but not large files.

This chat doesnt help https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=716957

Comment: Have you installed any of the MediaWiki modules/plugins/extensions? Do you have a vanilla MediaWiki install that you can test to see if files upload correctly...?

Comment: @BigChris Yes, I could upload images and ZIPs without any problem. A have a few typical extensión installed. Mediawiki is configured based on `https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Configuring_file_uploads`

Comment: Can you upload other PDF files of greater than 5MB? Can you upload other allowwed filetypes of grater than 5MB?

Comment: @BigChris You are right. It is imposible upload file more than 3Mb. Has it something to do with MS SQL/MaridDB?

Comment: The thumbnail error you're receiving may be fixed: https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Topic:Si3ofpvsr8utt336

Comment: @BigChris Well... This thumbnail erros appears when I upload fPDF files les 3MB  only in other cases is `A database query error has occurred. This may indicate a bug in the software`.

Comment: FPDF as in http://www.fpdf.org/?

Comment: What operating system are you running?  Have you installed GPL Ghostscript?   If you are running linux (please confirm the distro and version) please could you run `which ghostscript` and report back your results?  Also `which convert` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you need to install `GPL Ghostcript` and/or `ImageMagick` (for convert).

I need more information to help you further.